# Prove that a periodic continuous function is uniformly continuous. (W/O Heine-Borel etc.)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I began this way

Assume we have a periodic continuous function $f$. That is, there exists a $\delta$ such that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$ and $f(x+h)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and some $h\neq 0$. We wish to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous. That is, there exists a $\delta$ such that $0<|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-f(x+y)|<\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon>0$.

I know this seems like a duplicate but I have looked at the solutions and hints already posted and it is not. I need to do this without HB or anything past it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let $T$ be the period of $f$, $f:[0,T]\rightarrow R$ is uniformly continuous since $[0,T]$ is compact, you can use that show the result

Comment: How do you show $[0,T]$ compact without Heine-Borel?

Comment: You have to be careful: Your stated continuity is really uniform continuity, and the stated uniform continuity is not correct. You have to be careful about the quantifier (for all, there exists) when stating the theorems.

Comment: A periodic continuous function on $\mathbb Q$ need not be uniformly continuous.  If Heine-Borel is prohibited, what fact about $\mathbb R$ is allowed?

Comment: We can gather that $f$ is bounded

Comment: The standard proof to show that $[a,b]$ is compact is to consider a sequence $(x_n)$ to show that you can extract a subsequence which converges. The proof starts like this, $[a,(a+b)/2]$ or $[(a+b)/2,b]$ contain an infinite number of terms, take $x_{\phi(1)}$ in one of these intervals which contains an infinite number of terms, then construct $x_{\phi}(2)$ with the same process, and show that $(x_{\phi(n)]}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ be the period of $f$. On $[0,T+\zeta], \:\zeta>0$, $f$ is continuous and thus uniform continuous. So given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $0<\delta<\zeta$ such that for any $x,y\in[0,T+\zeta],\:|x-y|<\delta$, there is 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\tag1$$

Now consider any $x',y'\in\Bbb{R}$ that $|x'-y'|<\delta$. WLOG, assume $x'<y'$.

If $nT\leqslant x'<(n+1)T$ and $nT\leqslant y'<(n+1)T$, then there are $x,y\in[0,T]$ that $f(x)=f(x')$ and $f(y)=f(y')$. So by $(1)$
$$
|f(x')-f(y')|=|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon
$$
If $nT\leqslant x'<(n+1)T$ and $(n+1)T\leqslant y'<(n+2)T$, then there are $x,y\in[0,T+\zeta]$ that $f(x)=f(x')$ and $f(y)=f(y')$ for $\delta<\zeta$. So by $(1)$ again
$$
|f(x')-f(y')|=|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon
$$
So $f$ is uniform continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: This assumes that $f$ is uniformly continuous on a closed interval but we don't have that given?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on a closed interval means it is uniformly continuous. Read it again.

Comment: I apologize for missing the obvious but based on what?

Comment: It is a well known theorem in analysis, i.e. continuous function is always uniform continuous on compact set.

Comment: This theorem appears in every analysis text and so is a standard theorem. For example, Baby Rudin's text.

Comment: Not quite but I spoke with my professor and he informed me it is impossible to prove this without Heine-Borel

Comment: Yes, you need Heine-Borel to prove that continuous function is always uniform continuous on compact set. Normally, it is presumed. So this proof is good enough.